# A Redis distributed lock confusing result with Lua script

Tags: java, lua, redis, spring-data-redis

I use such code to achieve Redis distributed lock:

```
DefaultRedisScript<String> script = new DefaultRedisScript<>();
script.setScriptText("if not redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) then return redis.call('set', KEYS[1], ARGV[1],'ex',ARGV[2],'nx') else return false end");
String result = redisTemplate.execute(script,
            Collections.singletonList("REDIS_KEY_INDEX_LOCK"), "exists", "60");
```

I expect the result will be among `"OK"`, `"Nil"` and `"false"`.I checked the document, the `set` directive with `'NX'`,`'EX'` will return `"OK"` or `"Nil"`. 
My code's result is that the key `REDIS_KEY_INDEX_LOCK` is set with the value `exists` successfully in Redis, but the value of the Java variable `result` is `null`.
  `redisTemplatet` variable is a instance of `StringRedisTemplate` ,I'm use `Spring-Data-Redis`.

Please help me, explaining why I got an unexpected result and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason now after reading `Spring-Data-Redis` source code, the script's return type needs to be specified explicitly.

```
DefaultRedisScript<String> script = new DefaultRedisScript<>();
script.setScriptText("if not redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) \n" +
            "then if(redis.call('set', KEYS[1], ARGV[1],'EX',ARGV[2],'NX'))  \n" +
            "    then return \"true\";\n" +
            "    else return \"false\";\n" +
            "end\n" +
            "else return \"false\";\n" +
            "end");
script.setResultType(String.class);//need to specify return type explicitly
String result = redisTemplate.execute(script,
            Collections.singletonList("REDIS_KEY_INDEX_LOCK"),"exists","60");

return result.equals("true");
```